# Javascript Averaging Calculator(Multiple Values entered by the user)

Tags: javascript, average

I want to be able to have a user enter multiple grades and then have the Javascript to average those grades that are entered. When the user is done entering grades, they can click cancel and close the Propmt Box, and if they don't enter any grades at all (defaults at 0), then the program displays that there were no grades entered.

I'm pretty new at this! I'm taking a javascript course at my College, and it's a bit confusing because the teacher doesn't teach! All we have to reference to is W3schools, which this stuff isn't listed at all!

Here's another explanation:
"Develop a program to allow a teacher to enter an arbitrary number of grades, perform an average calculation and then display the result in a grammatical sentence. The program must also tell the user if no grades were entered. You are required to use a loop and an “if else” statement. Be sure to declare all variables and test for the possibility of division by zero."

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  var gradeCounter = 0,
    gradeValue = 0,
    total = 0,
    average, grade;
var sum = 0;
var i = 0;
while (gradeValue != -1 && gradeValue <= 100) {

  //Prompt the user
  grade = prompt("Enter Grades, -1 to Quit:", "0");
  //Parse the prompt result to a int
  sum += parseInt(grade);
  i++;
  if (i >= 0 && grade != null) {
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = "The average of the grades you've entered are " + sum / i + ".";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "There were no grades entered";
  }
} </script>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: what exactly is your question? need to ask a specific question for people to answer you.

Comment: Have you learned how to use the Javascript debugger yet? If not, that would be a good place to start. It lets you step through your code so that you can see exactly what is going on and you can compare that to what you think should be going on.

Comment: I want to know what's wrong my code, it's not working correctly.(for one, the prompt box isn't closing when I hit cancel). I got the program to average the grades. I also need it to tell me that No Grades were entered, if there weren't any entered.

Comment: @Bill, as I said I'm fairly new to this, and I really still don't know what I'm looking at 100%. I've been stressing over this program all day. I know it's supposed to be a simple grade averaging system. But I just can't do it!

Answer (score 1):

## this does ok

## updated

## updated again

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8vnzqhre/49/)

```
// note: the dom must be ready before execution

var btn = document.querySelector('button'),
    res = document.getElementById('average');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var val = prompt('Enter comma delimited grades to average');
    val = val.length ? val.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',') : '';
    
    var count = val.length || 0; // no 0 division

    if (!count) {
       res.innerHTML = 'you must enter comma delimited numbers to average';
       return;
    } else {
        var average = val.reduce(function(a, b) { // is a loop
            return +a + +b;
        });
        
        res.innerHTML = (average /= count).toFixed(1);        
    }

});
```

html

```
<button id="avgBtn">Prompt</button>
<p>Average: <span id="average"></span></p>
```

Comment: I am required to use a prompt box on a loop (to enter as many grades as I want). How can I integrate the two? Do you know? Also, I need the program to be able to tell if no grades were entered by the user, and for it to display a message "No grades were entered."

Comment: aight, dude. I think I deserve a right answer for doing your homework 3 times :P

Comment: Thanks! That will do, it does what is required, just a little bit different. That is neat how many ways you can do something. Thanks!

Comment: that's why I'm a total js nut-hugger

Comment: Haha, :) I would really love to learn more, but there's just not enough time ^_^.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var grades = [];
// initialize the array that will store the entries
var sum = 0;
// initialize the variable that will add the array values together
var average;
// initialize the variable that will contain the final result
var invalid = [];
// initialize the variable that will be used to make sure the user inserts something

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // repeat the following code 5 times

  grades[i] = prompt("Please enter a grade. (You will be asked for 5 grades)", "");
  // ask the user for a grade and store it to the array

}

for (i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
  if (grades[i] === "" || grades[i] === null) {
    invalid[invalid.length] = grades[i];
  }
}

if (invalid.length !== 5) {

  for (i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    // repeat this code the same amount of times as there are entries in the array (5)

    sum += Number(grades[i]);
    // add the entries together.  make sure they are numbers using the Number() function

  }

  var average = sum / grades.length;
  // divide the added entries by the number of entries (again, 5)

  alert("The average of all of your numbers is: " + average);
  // alert the user of the completed average
} else {

  alert('You need to enter grades for this to work!  Please reload the page to try again.');

}
```